# how can i play one song at a time in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, audio-player, android-music-player

In my music player if one song is already playing and if the user clicks on another song then that song also starts playing. In other words, there are multiple songs are playing at a single time this is really annoying. I want one song at a time. That means if a song is already playing and if the user clicks on another song then the previous song will gonna stop and the clicked song will gonna play.

> java code

```
  public void onItemClick(final Button b, View view, final SongInfo obj, int position) {


                if(b.getText().equals("Stop")){
                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                    mediaPlayer.reset();
                    mediaPlayer.release();
                    mediaPlayer = null;
                    b.setText("Play");
                }
                else {

                    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(obj.getSongUrl());
                                mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                                mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                                        mediaPlayer.start();
                                        seekBar.setProgress(0);
                                        seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
                                        Log.d("Prog", "run: " + mediaPlayer.getDuration());
                                    }
                                });
                                b.setText("Stop");
                                }catch (Exception e){}
                        }

                    };
                    myHandler.postDelayed(runnable,100);

                }
            }
        });
        checkUserPermission();
        Thread t = new runThread();
        t.start();
    }




    //Thread method for seek bar
    public class runThread extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Log.d("Runwa", "run: " + 1);
                if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                    seekBar.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            seekBar.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
                        }
                    });

                    Log.d("Runwa", "run: " + mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if("STOP".equalsIgnoreCase(b.getText()) {
    mediaPlayer.stop()  // stop the media player
    mediaPlayer.reset() // reset media player for re-use
    b.setText("Play");  // to re-play song
} else {
    // use the same instance of media-player if want to play single song at a time
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(obj.getSongUrl());
    mediaPlayer.prepare(); // can use prepareAsync() also
    mediaPlayer.start();
    b.setText("Stop");
}
```

To play only one song at a time, you have to use same instance of `mediaPlayer` object throughout. (See comments inline)

Ref : [Media Player State Diagram](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer#StateDiagram)