# MediaPlayer didn't play only one song at a time in Android Studio (JAVA)

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I want to make a simple music player app that plays songs on selected playlists. I successfully retrieve the details of the songs of the device.
I have a playlist of multiple songs. I want to play only one song at a time. but when I click on other songs already playing song didn't stop or pause. please give a complete solution with reason.

```
 ArrayList<SongModel> list;
```

SongModel Model Class

```
public class SongModel {

 String songImg,songName,songPath;
 Boolean isClick;

 public SongModel(String songImg, String songName, String songPath, Boolean isClick) {
    this.songImg = songImg;
    this.songName = songName;
    this.songPath = songPath;
    this.isClick = isClick;
 }

 public Boolean getClick() {
    return isClick;
 }

 public void setClick(Boolean click) {
    isClick = click;
 }

 public String getSongPath() {
    return songPath;
 }

 public void setSongPath(String songPath) {
    this.songPath = songPath;
 }

 public String getSongImg() {
    return songImg;
 }

 public void setSongImg(String songImg) {
    this.songImg = songImg;
 }

 public String getSongName() {
    return songName;
 }

 public void setSongName(String songName) {
    this.songName = songName;
  }
}
```

MediaPlayer used in Adapter

```
 MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, Uri.parse(list.get(position).getSongPath()));
    if(list.get(position).getClick()){
        holder.imgv_pause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.imgv_play.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        try {
            mediaPlayer.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        list.get(position).setClick(false);
        holder.imgv_pause.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.imgv_play.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        try {
            mediaPlayer.pause();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    holder.imgv_play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            for (int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
                list.get(i).setClick(false);
            }
            list.get(position).setClick(true);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    holder.imgv_pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            list.get(position).setClick(false);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Check if this reference helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52911667/how-can-i-play-one-song-at-a-time-in-android-studio

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop the pervious song when the user scroll in `onViewRecycled`  this function is called when the user scroll the **recycler-view**.

```
 @Override
    public void onViewRecycled(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
        super.onViewRecycled(holder);
      //stop song by its holder here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

only one song at a time in Android Studio
use this
**static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;**
*dont use Privet MediaPlayer mediaPlayer*

public class PlayerActivity<mgr, result, audioSession, getApplicationContext, phoneStateListener> extends AppCompatActivity implements MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener, AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener {

```
TextView songname, artistname, playduration, totalduration;
SeekBar seekBar;
ImageView backbutton, menu, playprevious, playnext, shufful;
ImageView play, repeat;
ImageView playalbum;
private Thread playThreads, previousThread, nextThread;
static ArrayList<Song> songlists = new ArrayList<>();
static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: brother check now